# Headphones only play right side

Tags: macbook-pro, headphones

My Macbook pro OS X 10.8.5 headphone jack seems to work - like it knows when I plug in the headphones - but it only plays out of the right side. I've adjusted the balance in settings but the left side stays silent. I've tried many different headphones and its always the same. Any suggestions?

Comment: You've tried other sets of headphones?  Your headphone port is damaged.

Answer (score 1):

I own a Shure headset with 3 connectors and it does **not** work on my MacBook Pro Retina 15''late 2013 nor does it with my iPhone 4S --- only the channel marked with 'left' works. And even the 4 connector versions are different among the various Notebook/Phone manufacturers compared to Apple. There are special Apple compatible versions advertised. Best, Peter

Answer (score -1):

does your headphone come with three electrical connectors at the plug or with for? The newer generations of MacBooks require 4 connectors to be able to play on both channels. Best Peter

Comment: No Apple computer or device require 4 part connectors. They work fine with no audio problems with both 3 and 4 part connectors.